# facebook publish POST API on iphone : Not publishing properly

Tags: cocoa-touch, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook publish API link this as given here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

```
NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SELF",@"value",nil] autorelease];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSString *privacyJSONStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:privacyDict];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"Test test", @"message",
                                     privacyJSONStr, @"privacy",
                                     @"http://www.facebook.com/", @"link",
                                     @"This name check where it will show", @"name",
                                     @"Caption for the link", @"caption",
                                     @"Longer description of the link", @"description",
                                     nil];
[facebookObj requestWithMethodName:@"facebook.Stream.publish" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

It posted successfully, but not like that as I expected
there is no caption, name, description , link etc
it shown as

[image]

This type of result I can get by this parameter

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"Test test", @"message",
                                         privacyJSONStr, @"privacy",
                                         nil];
```

What is the mistake, and How we can publish all the parameter

**Amit Battan**

Comment: are you sure that privacyJSONStr != nil ?

Comment: privacyJSONStr has not null value. it work fine in second case

Answer (score 0):

try this .. its works for me

```
- (IBAction )publishStream{

    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           @"Posting From",@"text",@"http://www.google.com/",@"href", nil], nil];

    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

    NSLog(@"Action Link String : %@", actionLinksStr);

    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Feed Name", @"name",
                                @"Feed Caption is here", @"caption",
                                @"Feed Description is here", @"description",
                                @"http://www.google.com/", @"href", nil];


    NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

    NSLog(@"Attachment String : %@", attachmentStr);

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                   attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                   nil];


    [facebook dialog:@"facebook.Stream.publish"
            andParams:params
          andDelegate:self];

}
```

Comment: ok i will try it.... why we have to give link it twice .. `http://www.google.com as href in actionLinks and also in attachment`